# jquery: select first child node

Tags: jquery, css

lets say i have a tree of the following structure:

```
<div>node level1
     <div>node level2
          <div>node level3...etc
```

Is there a way in jQuery, that if div level1 is clicked, only divs of level2 respond?

meaning:

```
$('div').click(function(){
$('div').children(first div child).css('color','red');
})
```

thanks for any input!

::EDIT::
hey everyone, thanks for your patience and input. i stubbornly went about solving this problem, and it worked out. i just had to find a way to crack inside the structure of my tree and it all became very clear. 
i basically wanted to find a way to make a superfish-esque tree collapse/expand without being stuck inside the "li ul li" examples i had been seeing as I felt they were a bit opaque.

[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qdqea/) has my solution. note: i am assuming that if something has 0 children it will most likely be a link to be followed. i am sure with the structure I have set out, and your able minds will be able to solve this last step.

thanks for all help and i look forward to any feedback. 
final note: this can be easily soft coded to agree with any tree structure size. a while loop that acknowledges children or node clicked, that allows for concatenation and calls an eval function will be able to drill all the way down in the sub-nodes and make sure they are all hidden before the main node is also hidden.

just a side thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).children('div').css('color','red');
});
```

Instead of selecting all `<div>` elements again, use `this` and do [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) from there to get the immediate child `<div>` elements.  [Here's a quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/b8AK3/), note for this example, the `<div>`s need a `color` initially, otherwise it'll cascade down...even though it wasn't actually applied to the level 3 elements.

Comment: nick
thank you for the response. let me specify my question with an example as well.

<html>
<head>
 <style>
  div { color: black; }
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>

 <body>
  <div>node level1
    <div>node level2
     <div>node level3...etc</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//css('color','red');
$('div').click(function(){

  $(this).find(":first-child").toggle();
  
});
});
</script>

demonstrates what i am attempting to do.

Comment: @user360826 - I'm not following...`.find()` will find `:first-child` at **each** level, which includes level 2 and 3, if you don't want level 3 you need `.children()` instead of `.find()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for:

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Edited for `.click()` context:

Inside the click event you'll have the `this` jQuery object to work with (which is the element which has been clicked.  So you can use the `.children()` to access all of the children elements (it will only return immediate children, so just items level-2 items in your scenario):

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(this).children().css('color','red');
}
```

Or, if you only want the *first* level-2 item you could use the `:first-child` selector:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $(':first-child', this).css('color','red');
}
```

Comment: yooder, thank you for the input. if you have a moment please look at the code i placed in Nick's response. it is exactly what i am trying to do.

Comment: @user360826 if your example is exactly what you want then it should be your solution--however the `.find()` call works with multiple levels of descendent/nested elements--I would really recommend spending sometime with jQuery's API and examining the differences between `.children()` and `.find()`-- they serve distinct purposes, and (as with all programming) it's important to understand their intended usages as well as their differences

Answer (score 0):

It's the matter of the css selector as jquery use it.

I think you could simply define a class to the div you want to select:

```
<div class="Level1">node level1
    <div class="Level2">node level2</div>
</div>
```

Then select it in jquery like this:

```
$('div.Level1').click(function(){
$(this).children('div.Level2').css('color','red');
})
```

Comment: adding a class just to use as a `.children()` selector is a bit redundant--if he's looking for all immeditate children of his level-1 div's then `.children()`, without a selector will give him what he's after without the extra (small) performance hit of running an extra seelctor

Comment: My solution should be straight forward if he / she only want to select level 1 and level 2 element.
performance depends on what he exactly want to do. his question is not clear actually.